# let $A,B\in M_{n}(C)$ such that c is complex field and $AB^2-B^2A=B$ how prove $B^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

Let $A,B\in M_{n}(C)$  such that $C$ is complex field and $AB^2-B^2A=B$. How prove $B^n=0$.
thanks in advance

Comment: If $B = \operatorname{diag}(i, 1)$, then $B^t B = \operatorname{diag}(-1,1)$ so has trace $0$, yet $B \neq 0$.  What am I missing?

Comment: thanks i think this point is for real matrix

Comment: Yes, for real matrices it's true that $B$ would have to be $0$, but didn't you specifically allowed $A$ and $B$ to be complex?

Comment: Great question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should note that $AB^{n+2}-B^{n+2}A=(n+1)B^{n+1}$ because
$AB^{n+2} - B^{n+2}A=(AB^2-B^2A)B^{n}+B^2(AB^{n}-B^{n}A)=B^{n+1}+B^2(nB^{n-1})=(n+1)B^{n+1}$ (this is a proof by induction in $n$).

This implies that $tr(B^n)$ is $0$ for all $n$ (because the trace of a commutator is always $0$). It is a nice exercise to show that this implies that $B$ is nilpotent.

IDEA: You have to work with the eigenvalues of $B$. The "easy" case is when $B$ has simple eigenvalues.

EDIT: This is a particular case of Jacobson's lemma. A nice [paper](http://jankobracic.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/on-the-jacobsons-lemma.pdf) on the subject.

EDIT II: If $B$ has simple eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots\lambda_k$ then $0=tr(B^n)=\sum \lambda_i^n$. Let $M$ be a matrix such that $M_{ij}=\lambda_i^j$. This matrix is a non-singular Vandermonde matrix and the vector $(1,\cdots,1)$ is in the kernel, this is a contradiction which came from the assumption that $B$ has simple eigenvalues. You should adapt this proof to the case where $B$ has a non-zero eigenvalue (and reach the same contradiction showing that $B$ has to be $0$).

EDIT III: As noted by user1551 in his comment the first part of the "proof" above only works for even $n$. However the second part of the proof using the Vandermonde matrix still works (but needs some modifications).

Comment: thanks sir.i trying to  prove the second part

Comment: sorry i read this part of paper but a cant prove second part  can you help me more thanks

Comment: There are several issues in your proof. First, the induction assumption should be $AB^{n+2}-B^{n+2}A = \frac{n+2}{2}B^{n+1}$ for every **even** $n\ge0$. So, the immediate conclusion should be $tr(B^{n+1})=0$ for every **even** $n$, not $tr(B^n)=0$ for **all** $n$. And $tr(B^n)=0$ for all $n$ doesn't imply that $B=0$ (e.g. take $B$ to be a nontrivial Jordan block with zero eigenvalues).

Comment: @Quimey The amended proof is still leaky. We have $tr(B^{n+1})=0$ for every even $n$, or equivalently, $tr(B^n)=0$ for every odd $n$. So the Vandermonde-like matrix should be defined by $M_{ij}=\lambda_i^{2j-1}$, i.e. the power for each entry should be odd. Now, even if all eigenvalues of $B$ are simple, $M$ can be still be singular because it may happen that $\lambda_i=-\lambda_j$ for some $i,j$.

Comment: Your observation is part of the "modifications" needed. Let $n_i$ be the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ plus the multiplicity of $-\lambda_i$ (counting once each pair). We have that the vector $(n_i \lambda_i)_i$ is in the kernel and it is not zero.

Answer (score 2):

The equality $AB^2-B^2A=B$ implies that $PAP^{-1}(PBP^{-1})^2-(PBP^{-1})^2PAP^{-1}=PBP^{-1}$ for any invertible matrix $P$. Therefore, we may assume WLOG that $B$ is already in its Jordan form. Let $B=J_1\oplus J_2\oplus\ldots\oplus J_k$, where $J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_k$ are Jordan blocks of possibly different sizes. Let those diagonal blocks of $A$ with conforming sizes be $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$. Then $AB^2-B^2A=B$ implies that $A_iJ_i^2-J_i^2A_i=J_i$ for each $i$. Since the LHS has zero trace, the $J_i$ on the RHS must have a zero diagonal. Therefore $B$ is nilpotent and $B^n=0$.